# Is this negative resistor model valid for any type of LC self oscillating circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, oscillator, theory, modeling

Is the following negative resistance model valid for any type of LC oscillator? If not, what are the exceptions?

[image]

Image Source is from [here](http://www.cypress.com/file/88466/download)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All oscillators have negative resistance , it applies only to resonant frequency and may be different during startup and if clipping or any non-linear characteristic.